# File write from linux kernel driver failed

Tags: c, linux-kernel

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    struct file* my_fd;

    my_fd = filp_open ("/tmp/foobar", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0);
    if (IS_ERR (my_fd))
    {
    printk (KERN_ERR "Failed to open file. err: %d.\n", my_fd);
    }
    else
    {
    my_fd->f_op->write (my_fd, "some data", 10, &my_fd->f_pos);
    }

printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "hello_end.\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

the above code is giving error -14 while writing in the file. what am I doing wrong here?

Here is the `dmesg` output:

```
[19551.674999] Write returned: -14.
[19551.675004] Loading hello module...
```

Comment: You could probably try to start by looking up what error code -14 means.

Comment: @JSBangs, 14 is EFAULT, this is what I couldn't figure out that why it is coming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `write` member of `struct file_operations` (in `include/linux/fs.h`) is declared like this:

```
 ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

Note the `__user` token on the second argument, which tells you it is expecting a *user-space* pointer.  When you call it like you did from the kernel, you are passing a *kernel-space* pointer; hence your memory fault.

@ShinTakezou's link to the "acct.c" code is what you want to look at; in particular, the calls to `set_fs` to trick the kernel into using its own data segment as the "user" data segment.

Comment: +1 This is also why looking up the error code is a good idea: `$ grep 14 /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-10/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h 
#define EFAULT  14 /* Bad address */`

Comment: These days there are `kernel_read()` and `kernel_write()` helpers which safely wrap `vfs_read/write` in `set_fs()`. (Ignoring the side issue, that you probably want to use sysfs or similar instead of direct filesystem access).

Answer (score 2):

First, do not ignore warnings: your `%d` is not good for `my_fd`.

Then, I think in general it is not a good idea to do file I/O from kernel, except in "special" cases.

I've tried with O_CREAT and everything is fine except if the file already exists. Everything else (in particular `O_WRONLY | O_APPEND`) gave me no chance.

I believe that in order to make file I/O in kernel "as" in user space requires to know more stuffs, and it is likely a bit tricky (or "dangerous").

However try to look at the [acct.c](http://www.kernel.org/pub//scm/linux/kernel/git/jejb/storage-tree/kernel/acct.c) code.

Comment: +1 Thanks. acct.c code helped, but adding the O_CREAT flag didn't fix the problem. However using the user space buffer solved it.